# Why is the year dropdown in JQuery datepicker not being displayed in firefox 25.0?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, datepicker, z-index

I'm using the JQuery datepicker in a modal. Everything works fine except that the year dropdown is not showing up when clicked. The z-index of the modal is less than that of the datepicker. All other components on the datepicker respond to click event but not the year dropdown. It works perfectly in chrome.
I checked the z-index by inspecting elements. The z-index is 3 as shown in the html but in the css panel it shows that the z-index: 3 has be striked off and a value of 10000 !important is being used which I put on purpose.But it still won't work

Comment: please provide url or jsfiddle so that somebody can check the error for you..

Comment: I'm sorry but its difficult to recreate that scenario